# Run a macro while you are actively in a cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code.  I want to have my cursor active in a cell, run the macro, and have the vba put the string of periods onto the clipboard then paste them into the cell where my cursor is active.  Can this be done?

```
Dim obj As New DataObject

Dim txt As String

'Put some text inside a string variable

txt = ".............................."

'Make object's text equal above string variable

obj.SetText txt

'Place DataObject's text into the Clipboard

obj.PutInClipboard
```

Comment: You cant run a code while in edit mode inside a cell. You may be better off displaying a message box of some sorts to have the user select where the want to insert your series of periods. Maybe something with a double click change event? I'm sure there are a few ways to do this but you will need to rework the logic here. Is there a pattern that can be used to determine where the periods should be entered? You can also have a change event to just add them in at the end of every edit?

Comment: I did find [this](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-code-for-cursor-position-within-a-cell.858432/) that may be of interest but overall this approach looks like overkill. I'm sticking with my comment on your first post that your problem is by design. Find a better way to track history so you don't have to deal with problems like this. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your last question you may be able to use a `Worksheet_Change` event to simply add your periods at the end of the string after every edit.

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.CountLarge = 1 Then
    If Len(Target) > 0 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target = Target & "......"
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End If    

End Sub
```

You can customize this to a degree if this route is feasible. For instance, right now the macro ignores any changes that result in the cell being blank (*i.e. you can still clear a cell with normal functionality*). As per @BigBen's suggestion, the macro also ignores changes that apply to multiple cells at once (*i.e. pasting a range to your sheet*) You can also amend this to only fire if the cell changed is in a certain row/column. etc.

---

[image]

Comment: Might be worth putting a `If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub` too...

Comment: @BigBen thanks - i've never used `CountLarge` so good to know. Updated!